# What is the name of that phenomenon in which a straight line/trajectory appears curved?

Tags: classical-mechanics

[RESOLVED (see edit)]

Like for example, depending on where you are relative to one object, and the angle of it , etc., it'll appear either straight or curved but is in fact a straight thread (or curved, I forget)? I'm not sure if I'm explaining this correctly though.

EDIT: AH I got it!! I phrased it completely inaccurately making it sound like a visual sensation when it is in fact an inertia-driven one, but the thing I was referring to was "CORIOLIS"..!

Thanks to all taking the time anyhow!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I was basically looking for the name of 'Coriolis force' but after some digging  was able to find it myself. So now the question's betrothed with its answer. ^^'

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a type of optical illusion. Some possibilities from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_optical_illusions):

- Café wall illusion

[image]

- Ehrenstein illusion

[image]

- Hering illusion

[image]

- Wundt illusion

[image]